# using scipy's stats.linregress with a fixed y intercept

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I was wondering if it was possible to use stats.linregress except with a fixed y-intercept, I am currently doing this,:

```
from scipy import stats
from numpy import arrange,array

y = [0, 11, 19, 28, 41, 49, 62, 75, 81]
xi = arange(0,9)

scale, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,y)
```

It would be preferrable if I could still ascertian a R value

Answer (score 0):

From the [domcumentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html) of scipy it is not possible. But you can use something else like [statsmodel](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html):

```
y = [0, 11, 19, 28, 41, 49, 62, 75, 81]
x = arange(0,9)
model = sm.OLS(y,x)
results = model.fit()
print(results.params)
```